Got "ETIMEDOUT" error when calling api from docker container with axios
I'm trying to scrape a website and send an alert to Telegram after scraping. It was working in the local environment without Docker. After setting it up with Docker, I started getting a "ETIMEDOUT" error while sending alert. I'm confused why this error is happening since I can still scrape the website. I've tried restarting the container and adding Google DNS, but it's still not working consistently. Sometimes, it works for a couple of tries and then keeps failing. I am quite sure that the url is correct too. My os is Ubuntu.
I made some testing with other api. It's working when I call google.com and jsonplaceholder. Not working only with telegram bot api. The domain is https://api.telegram.org. Others said to use proxy. But I live in Thailand and can't even call from my local docker container.
Here's my Axios code and the error message.
  async sendToTelegram(text: string) {
    let token = process.env.TELEGRAM_BOT_TOKEN;

    let url = `https://api.telegram.org/bot${token}/sendMessage`;

    console.log(url);

    let group_id = process.env.TELEGRAM_GROUP_ID;

    let params = {
        chat_id: group_id ? group_id : "",
        text
    };

    await axios.get(url, { params });
}



It might be that the Docker MTU causes that problem. To fix it, you need to add this to your /etc/docker/daemon.json.
{
  "mtu": 1450
}

This will set mtu to 1450 when you use docker run. If you use docker compose, then you don't need to edit that file, but instead configure it directly in your docker-compose.yml file like this:
networks:
  default: # Or your network name
    driver: bridge
    driver_opts:
      com.docker.network.driver.mtu: 1450

By default, Docker MTU is set to 1500. In the above setup, it is set to 1450. To find out the MTU number on your Ubuntu machine, you can run
$ ip link | grep mtu

1: lo: <LOOPBACK,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 65536 qdisc noqueue state UNKNOWN mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
2: ens3: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1450 qdisc fq_codel state UP mode DEFAULT group default qlen 1000
3: docker0: <NO-CARRIER,BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP> mtu 1500 qdisc noqueue state DOWN mode DEFAULT group default

Then, pick the number from your network card. In this case, it is ens3.

I tried both 1450 and 1500 on my docker compose file. But still not working. When I check the MTU with ip link | grep mtu, I have eth0 and eth1. Both are 1500. I am running on Digital Ocean droplet.

I followed what is here described here: https://help.nordlayer.com/docs/docker-mtu-configuration
I used a named network instead "default" and I configure the "networks:" property on each services. That changes the "mtu" but Telegram Bot with axios is still failing.

Got the answer now. Problem is docker image. It seems like alpine docker image has network problem. After changing to other images, not issue at all.
